# HDMI vs VGA: Which one consumes more power?

Tags: hdmi

I just switched to HDMI recently for my gaming. Could anybody tell how much power is being consumed when using HDMI compared to the old VGA?

Comment: I can't answer your question, but I'm pretty sure any difference would be dwarfed by the power drawn by rest of the machine.

Answer (score 5):

Almost 100% of the power used for graphics is used by the video card itself for its calculations.  The output signal, whether its VGA, DVI, HDMI, or DP it's practically nothing.

If you were to measure it, there would probably be *some* difference, but its virtually unnoticeable in comparison to the power required to operate the card.

Comment: Nice. But also to remember that all the graphics interfaces aren't "active" like, say, USB. This goes hand-in-hand with what you say. Any computer display requires its own power supply so the interface (HDMI, VGA etc.), as said, will demand minimal power.